# Как вывести значение словаря, преобразовав его из списка в строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть словарь:

```
d = {'Коля':[1, 2, 3], 'Вася':[4, 5, 6]}
```

нужно вывести его вот так:

```
Коля:1, 2, 3  
Вася:4, 5, 6
```

если попробовать вот так:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    print(key, ':', value, sep='')
```

получается:

```
Коля:[1, 2, 3] 
Вася:[4, 5, 6]
```

используя функцию str()

```
for key, value in d.items():
    print(key, ':', str(value), sep='')
```

результат аналогичный

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно пробежаться по `value`, применить к каждому элементу `str()`, а потом объединить полученные строки с помощью `join` с нужным разделителем:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    print(key, ':', ', '.join(str(num) for num in value), sep='')
```

Comment: 1- можно `', '.join(map(str, list_value))` использовать вместо `', '.join(str(num) for num in list_value)` 2- можно явное форматирование использовать: `print('{}:{}'.format(name, ', '.join(map(str, list_value))))`

Answer (score 0):

Если value - это список int-чисел, то можно просто срезать первый и последний символы после преобразования списка в строку:
    `str(value)[1:-1]`

Comment: Можно, но если будет, например, список имен `['Коля', 'Вася', 'Петя']`, то при выводе они так и будут в кавычках. Но для чисел работать будет.

Comment: лучше так не делать, т.к. `str(list)` вызывает `repr(item)` для каждого элемента, а не `str(item)`.

Answer (score 0):

Вывод Значений в одну строку:

```
friends =  {'Серёга': 'Омск', 'Соня': 'Москва', 'Дима': 'Челябинск', 'Витя': 'Лондон', 'Егор': 'Вятка'}

print("Вот в каких городах живут мои друзья: "+', '.join(friends.values()))
```

Результат:

> Вот в каких городах живут мои друзья: Омск, Москва, Челябинск, Лондон,
>   Вятка

Comment: Ресультат, который ожидает ТС, и ваш не совпадают. Внимательно ли вы прочитали вопрос?